# Dockerize Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker

I'm taking a look at Dockerization of Spring Boot Apps.

Unfortunately I can not get a working Project.
Even the official [Tutorial Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) from Pivotal will not start.

The command `.\mvnw install dockerfile:build` throws an error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.886 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-03T11:20:52+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/536M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.4:build (default-cli) on project gs-spring-boot-docker: Could not build image: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.spotify.docker.client.messages.RegistryAuth: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('wincred')
[ERROR] at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["credsStore"])
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you build your application with `mvn package`? Does it run when you have built it locally? What's your Dockerfile like?

Comment: I can build it and run it locally (Run as Spring Boot app).
The Dockerfile is simply the [original](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker/blob/master/complete/Dockerfile) from the Pivot tutorial:

Comment: this example works for me; so with no more info about your pom or Dockerfile I can't help

Comment: I haven't changed neither the Dockerfile nor the pom.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent docker update he required the field `auths` in ~/.docker/config.json

This fixes it for me on my mac.

```
    {
      "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
      },
      "credsStore" : "osxkeychain",
      "credSstore" : "osxkeychain"
     }
```